# Confused in Calling function in angularjs using anchortag

Tags: angularjs

i am working on one angularjs project.i have one dropdown in which new email,new contact,new calendar function is there.but these function is working on perticular page only like newmessage function works only on Email page.

i want to call the newMessage function, newAddressbook and new calendar functon from anywhere...
can you help me.

this is my code for that functions.:-

```
<a ng-href="" ng-click="mailbox.newMessage($event)">Email</a>
             <a href="" ng-click="app.newAddressbook()">Contact</a>
            <a href="" ng-click="app.newCalendar()" >Calendar</a>
```

Comment: embed inside a div and place the ng-click for the div

Comment: try: `href="javascript:void(0)"` for calling anywhere define in root file: `app.js` with `$rootScope`.

Answer (score 1):

There may be few details which you might have missed , try embedding controller to the respective div which you are using .
Or you can declare the scope as "**root**" ('$rootScope') into your model . 
Hope this will help .

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

In your app.js write following code

```
app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.newMessage = function($event) {
        // do something
    }
    $rootScope.newAddressbook = function($event) {
        // do something
    }
    $rootScope.newCalendar = function($event) {
        // do something
    }
}]);
```

In Safari and IE "javascript:void(0)" is treated as unsafe so include following code into your app config

```
app.config(['$compileProvider',function($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|javascript|chrome-extension):/);
}])
```

// html code

```
<a ng-href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="$root.newMessage($event)">Email</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="$root.newAddressbook($event)">Contact</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="$root.newCalendar($event)" >Calendar</a>
```

Comment: thaks for giving solution.

Comment: where to put the upper js code. i have so many js file.. and what to write in that "do something" block?

Comment: @VikasPatel - Put that code into your app.js file where you have initialized your angular app.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('SOGo.Common')
   app.controller('navController', navController);
 app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.newMessage = function($event) {
        // do something
    }
    $rootScope.newAddressbook = function($event) {
        // do something
    }
    $rootScope.newCalendar = function($event) {
        // do something
    }
}]);
 


});
```

Comment: i am using the above code in navcontroller.js file...but its not working